# "Corrected" or actual odometry Data

Tags: navigation, odometry, rviz, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Right now I'm playing around with a node which build a GridCells and publishes it. It also broadcasts a transform that says the GridCells are aligned exactly on the map I have.

Then, when the node receives 'odom' data, it adds a cell corresponding to the odom position data to the GridCells.cells list. When I run it in rviz, I want to simply have the path that the turtlebot has taken
to be traced out. Everything works great except the odom traced does not line up with the turtlebot and is offset by a few meters.

Where can I get the actual or "corrected" or the position of the robot that the gmapping node thinks it is. Essentially I'm asking how gmapping, or rviz or tf or move_base (not sure which one) knows where the robot is. How is the position of the robot model determined and is that position published?

Thanks for all the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40236/%22corrected%22-or-actual-odometry-data/) by [bgagnon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2657/bgagnon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The usual robot localization data is in the transform map->base_link. You need to [listen to this tf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29)

Do note that the path traced out using this localization data may have discrete jumps as explained in the [REP105](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html#coordinate-frames)

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bgagnon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2657/bgagnon/) on 2012-08-01**:
That should be ok for what I'm doing, thanks!